# How to populate a select field with post titles/ids in a block

Tags: posts, block-editor, select

I need to build a really simple block with just one select field. This select field should be populated with the titles/ids of posts of a specific post type. Once a user selects one post from this select field, its id should be saved in a particular attribute.

I have most of the code written, I just need to complete the part that populates the select field with all the posts of a specific post type published in my site.

I know that I must use the `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords()` selector somewhere, but I have no idea how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export const settings = {
    title: __( 'Post Selection', 'plugin-domain' ),
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            default: 0,
        },
    },

    edit: props => {
        const attributes = props.attributes;

        const setID = value => {
            props.setAttributes( { id: value } );
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <SelectControl
                    label={ __( 'Select a post:', 'plugin-domain' ) }
                    value={ attributes.id }
                    options={ ... fill with all post titles/ids of a specific post type ... }
                    onChange={ setID }
                />
            </div>
        );

    },

    save: props => { ... omitted for brevity ... }

};

registerBlockType( 'my/postselectblock', settings );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution myself. To get a list of posts of a specific post type one must wrap the `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords()` selector inside the `withSelect` higher order component, which is a function that provides props to a component using selectors. Then, we can populate a SelectControl with this data.

```
export const settings = {
    title: __( 'Post Selection', 'plugin-domain' ),
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            default: 0,
        },
    },

    edit: withSelect( ( select ) => {
        return {
            posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'my_custom_post_type', { per_page: -1 } )
        };
    } )
    ( props => {
        const { attributes, className } = props;

        const setID = value => {
            props.setAttributes( { id: Number( value ) } );
        };

        if ( ! props.posts ) {
            return __( 'Loading...', 'plugin-domain' );
        }

        if ( props.posts.length === 0 ) {
            return __( 'No posts found', 'plugin-domain' );
        }

        var options = [];
        options.push( {
            label: __( 'Choose a post...', 'plugin-domain' ),
            value: ''
        } );

        for ( var i = 0; i < props.posts.length; i++ ) {
            options.push( {
                label: props.posts[i].title.raw,
                value: props.posts[i].id
            } );
        }

        return (
            <Placeholder
                key='post-selection-block'
                icon='admin-post'
                label={ __( 'Post Selection Block', 'plugin-domain' ) }
                className={ className }>
                    <SelectControl
                        label={ __( 'Select a post:', 'plugin-domain' ) }
                        value={ attributes.id }
                        options={ options }
                        onChange={ setID }
                    />
            </Placeholder>
        );

    } ),

    save( { attributes } ) {
        ... omitted for brevity ...
    },

};

registerBlockType( 'my/postselectblock', settings );
```